# Overloading method invoke issue

Tags: java, overloading

Please let me know as Overloading is Compile Time Polymorphism and it consider reference variable for invoking the method. suppose if we have parameter overloaded method than which overloaded method will call will be decided by parameter or object throw which we are invoking method.

Please find below my code:

```
package com.overload;

class Bird {
    public void call(Bird bird) {
        System.out.println("Bird");
    }
}

class Crow extends Bird {
     void call(Crow bird) {
        System.out.println("Crow" );
    }
}
public class OverloadApp {    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Bird bird = new Bird();
        Bird crowBird = new Crow();
        Crow crow = new Crow();

        bird.call(bird);  // 1 - O/P:Bird
        bird.call(crow);  // 2 - O/P:Bird
        bird.call(crowBird);// 3 - O/P: Bird

        crow.call(bird); // 4 - O/P:Bird
        crow.call(crow); // 5 - O/P:Crow
        crow.call(crowBird); // 6 - O/P:Bird

        crowBird.call(bird); // 7 - O/P:Bird
        crowBird.call(crow); // 8 - O/P:Bird
        crowBird.call(crowBird); // 9 - O/P:Bird
    }
}
```

For  `bird.call(crow);  // 2 - O/P:Bird` - bird will decide which overloaded method is called or parameter crow decides which overloaded method is called.

As after seeing the O/P I am bit confused.

Thanks,
Kamal

Comment: What's your question? This isn't very clear.

Comment: Hello, Just wanted to know why O/P 2 is bird I was thinking it should be Crow as I have passed crow object (also the reference) and which overloaded method will be called is decided by reference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This invocations

> ```
>     bird.call(crow);  // 2 - O/P:Bird
>     crowBird.call(crow); // 8 - O/P:Bird
> ```

call `call(Bird bird)` because the *declared type* of both variables is `Bird` which only knows the `Bird` version of the method. It does not know the other one.

But variable `crow` is declared to be a `Crow` so that there are two methods to choose from...

---

> If this is the case than why
>       `crow.call(bird); // 4 - O/P:Bird`
>   and
>       `crow.call(crowBird); // 6 - O/P:Bird`
>    are Bird. In these 2 scenarios O/P should be "Crow" as declared type is `Crow`. – Kamal Verma

No. 
Because variable `bird` and `crowBird` are declared to be of type `Bird` they cannot be passed to the *Crow* version of the method, although it is available for variable `crow`.

Comment: If this is the case than why    crow.call(bird); // 4 - O/P:Bird and  crow.call(crowBird); // 6 - O/P:Bird are Bird. In these 2 scenarios O/P should be Crow as declared type is Crow.

Comment: Yes, my bad.. got it..Thanks